Bidieved, if one davens Shemoneh Esrei with Chazarat Hashatz, is it considered Tefillah Bztibbur?
Let's say someone comes a bit late to Shacharit or if the Minyan is very fast. Bidieved, if one started Shemoneh Esrei with the Chazan's repetition, is this considered Tefillah Bztibbur?

IIRC there is a minority opinion that says it is.
